# IBM MFP - Customization of Administrator message

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

See attached image. We currently create System Administrator messages prompts by using the ff. [image: IMAGE 1]

We system maintenance message we get is the ff:

[image: IMAGE 2]

Now, what we would like to do this, customize this message prompt. Can this be done? Customize meaning have our own wordings for the header (to replace "Application Disabled") and also our own look and feel for the prompt.

We already have done the customization of Application force update messafe by using the hook onErrorRemoteDisableDenial in WL.Client.init . Can this be done too for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this and change the user interface of the Application Disabled pop up notification by using challenge handler for `wl_remoteDisableRealm` security check.

The following is the sample code of challenge handler of `wl_remoteDisableRealm` which i have written in swift.

```
//
//  RemoteDisable.swift
//  PinCodeSwift
//
//  Created by Vittal Pai on 11/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Sample. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation

class RemoteDisable : SecurityCheckChallengeHandler {

    //SecurityCheck name
    static let securityCheck = "wl_remoteDisableRealm"

    //Register this class as a challenge handler
    static func registerSelf() {
        WLClient.sharedInstance().registerChallengeHandler(RemoteDisable(securityCheck: securityCheck))
    }

    override func handleChallenge(_ challenge: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {
        NSLog("%@",challenge)

        guard let challangeInfo = challenge as? [String: Any] else {
            self.cancel()
            return
        }

        guard let messageId = challengeInfo["messageId"] as? String else {
            self.cancel()
            return
        }
        var message = challengeInfo["message"]

        if  message == nil {
            message = "Your own message"
        }

        self.submitChallengeAnswer(["messageId": messageId])
        showPopup(messageId,remainingAttempts: 1)
    }

    override func handleFailure(_ failure: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {

    }

    func showPopup(_ errorMsg: String, remainingAttempts: Int){
        let message = errorMsg + "\nRemaining attempts: " + String(remainingAttempts)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Protected",
                                      message: message,
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "PIN CODE"
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            let pinTextField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
           // self.submitChallengeAnswer(["pin": pinTextField.text!])
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
          //  self.cancel()
        }))

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController! as UIViewController
            topController.present(alert,
                                  animated: true,
                                  completion: nil)
        }


    }

    func showError(_ errorMsg: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error",
                                      message: errorMsg,
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController! as UIViewController
            topController.present(alert,
                                  animated: true,
                                  completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func handleSuccess(_ success: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {
        NSLog("ha1ndleSuccess: %@",success)
    }

}
```